# What is the easiest approach to render an image from mongodb?

Tags: javascript, html, mongodb, image, blob

I created a database that stores images as binary data, but when I fetch images using the fetch api and use blob on the response I have just no idea how to display it, how can I render a blob object as an image? Or are there better and easier approaches to take?

Answer (score 1):

When you are trying to save in MongoDB, you have to save the image type too.
as well as below

```
const imageData= fs.readFileSync(incomingImage.path);
const input = new ImageModel():
item.image = new MongoDb.Binary(imageData);
item.imageType = incomingImage.type;
item.imageName = incomingImage.name;
item.save();
```

consider `imageModel` is your own schema for image collection
then create an API to send the image data

```
res.contentType(result.imageType);    
res.end(result.image.buffer, "binary");
```